# Trying to make the smallest possible nested circles with css

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox

Im working on a Vue component, where the user can add circles in to other circles, with support for unlimited levels of nesting, but im having some problems with the CSS.

**Here is a simplified version of the problem:**

Im trying to achieve something like this.[image: goal of the html and css]

I thought `flexbox` would be a great choice for that job, but cant make it work how i want it to, it always ends up way too big and not breaking up into separate lines or breaking out of the circles.

I have tried this approach, im open for a new structure if there is an easer way to do this. As long as the circle have a title and content, thought about using `before` and `after` for the title and content to simplify the structure, but haven't explored that option yet.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".circle").forEach( el => el.style.height = window.getComputedStyle(el).width);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.head {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}
.body {
  align-items: center;
}
.red {
  background-color: rgba(255, 17, 0, 0.76);
}
.blue {
  background-color: rgba(8, 0, 255, 0.76);
}
.green {
  background-color: rgba(0, 157, 11, 0.76);
}
```

```html
<div id="circle_test">
    <div id="master" class="red circle flex">
    
        <div class="head">
            Parent
        </div>
        <div class="body flex">
            <div class="blue circle">
                <div class="head">
                    child-0
                </div>
                <div class="body flex">
                    <div class="green circle">
                        <div class="head">sub-child-0</div>
                        <div class="body">content here</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="green circle">
                        <div class="head">sub-child-1</div>
                        <div class="body">content here</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="green circle">
                        <div class="head">sub-child-2</div>
                        <div class="body">content here</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="blue circle">
                <div class="head">
                    child-1
                </div>
                <div class="body flex">
                    <div class="green circle">
                        <div class="head flex">sub-child-0</div>
                        <div class="body">content here</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

or as a [jsfiddle.net link](https://jsfiddle.net/drt1hn6t/)

Any inputs are appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: If you add `align-items:flex-start`/`align-content: flex-start` the circles will align at the top: https://jsfiddle.net/drt1hn6t/1/

Comment: The main issues here is that with the script you set a `height`, which, if one resize the window, needs to be executed again to adjust to the new viewport, and if any child/sub-child might have wrapped, or else the child item will overflow its parent. Furthermore, when you run it, you also need to check whether a circle is higher than wider, and when, adjust the `width` instead. This issue can be seen in the inline stack snippet (viewed w/o using "Fullpage"), where the parent never becomes wider than the viewport, and should have its width adjusted instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is a simplified version of the the problem (i have taken care of resize and item changes), i have tried with the `align-items` and `align-content`, but im trying break the circles from a row into what fits in the circle.

Comment: To make circle _fill_ itself better, you need to count the items and have a method that _knows_ how many per row will be needed to optimize the space, and then, with that method, add delimiter elements, having zero height and full width, which will force a wrap. Maybe something like this, [https://jsfiddle.net/drt1hn6t/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/drt1hn6t/2/), where I added a `delimiter` in the first child to force a _wrap_.

Comment: Another sample with more sub-children: https://jsfiddle.net/drt1hn6t/3/

Comment: Thanks, ill try and write some JS to take care of the height and width, and see how it reacts.

Comment: I'm almost sure you don't need JS to take care of the height and width. You should try CSS Grid Layout to build that. Flexbox is meant to build one-dimensional layouts and Grid Layout two-dimensional layouts. You can read more in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve something visually similar with d3.js:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(2,2)"),
  format = d3.format(",d");

  var pack = d3.pack()
  .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4]);

  var circles = '{ "name": "Parent", "children": [ { "name": "child-0", "children": [ {"name": "sub-child-0", "size": 100}, {"name": "sub-child-1", "size": 100}, {"name": "sub-child-2", "size": 100} ] }, { "name": "child-1", "children": [ {"name": "sub-child-0", "size": 100} ] } ]}';

  var circlesParse = JSON.parse(circles);

  circlesParse = d3.hierarchy(circlesParse)
  .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
  .data(pack(circlesParse).descendants())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

  node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }).append("text")
  .attr("dy", "0.3em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.name.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
```

```css
circle {
    fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);
    fill-opacity: .25;
    stroke: rgb(31, 119, 180);
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

  .leaf circle {
    fill: #ff7f0e;
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }

  text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    text-anchor: middle;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="250" height="250"></svg>
```

Inspired by https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530